# 'Node' is undefined. How can we define in application level?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, scope, global-variables

I am facing some problem with variable scope. If we define in one js file and how can we use in another js file (here I mean to say if we want to use one variable in entire application)? Is it we can do?

Example: In our IE (IE-8 and lower versions of IE)  we are facing problem with node types. We are using constants in so many javascript files Example: Node.ELEMENT_NODE
this is giving problems with few browsers( 'Node' is undefined)
We have to replace this constant with "1" in all files. Instead of replacing this in all places (so many files), can we define in our starting html file with

Example as below in our starting html file (i.e. index.html) and can we use Node.ELEMENT_NODE in any other javascript files? does it impact in all other javascript files where ever we use Node.ELEMENT_NODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window.Node){
        Node = {  
            ELEMENT_NODE                :  1,
            ATTRIBUTE_NODE              :  2,
            TEXT_NODE                   :  3,
            CDATA_SECTION_NODE          :  4,
            ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE       :  5,
            ENTITY_NODE                 :  6,
            PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE :  7,
            COMMENT_NODE                :  8,
            DOCUMENT_NODE               :  9,
            DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE          : 10,
            DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE      : 11,
            NOTATION_NODE               : 12
        };
    }
```

Comment: If you try what you suggest, does it generate an error ?

Comment: It is working in that file (example index.html) only. If I use same variable in another file (another.js) is not applied this value. I am getting error as 'Node' is undefined. Just looking for declaring in one file and wants to use in all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file where you put you javascript code.

```
// your-script.js
if (!window.Node){
    Node = {  
        ELEMENT_NODE                :  1,
        ATTRIBUTE_NODE              :  2,
        TEXT_NODE                   :  3,
        CDATA_SECTION_NODE          :  4,
        ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE       :  5,
        ENTITY_NODE                 :  6,
        PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE :  7,
        COMMENT_NODE                :  8,
        DOCUMENT_NODE               :  9,
        DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE          : 10,
        DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE      : 11,
        NOTATION_NODE               : 12};
    }
}
```

Then, add this line on every page of your site :

```
<script src="your-script.js"></script>
```

The best is to put this line just before the `</body>` (closing tag). This will execute the javascript after everything else has been loaded.
Of course, you can still place this line where you want.

Note : here, the file is called "your-script.js", but you can name it as you want.

This will include the code in all your pages. It will then be accessible from everywhere.

---

If you still have issues with this solution, wait for all the scripts to be loaded before executing any code :

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    // Javascript code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Is there any other way without modifying other files just declaring in single file and should reflect in all other files. (As you suggested to add in all files: <script src="your-script.js"></script>). If we declare in one file can it reflect in all files?

Comment: If you're using a template system, add the line in your template.
If not, you'll have to manually add this to get the code working on every page, otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: actually at present there is no template. And i tried your suggestion (window.onload = function ()...). no luck with it. Thanks.

Comment: The second solution only works if you load the javascript in all the pages but the code gets executed before some other code is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that script is at the top of every page.  Forget about placing it before your closing body tag or placing it in the onload event. Creating a plain Javascript object with simple properties shouldn't cause a noticeable difference when loading a page.